# How to write test to formGroup created by foreach

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have created reusable form for questions and answers.
The interface looks like:

```
export interface QuestionFormData {
  title: string;
  questions: Question[];
}
```

Question interface is:

```
export interface Question {
  questionContent: string;
  answers: {key: string, value: any}[]; //it is like valueToDisplay: string, valueToPut: any
  nameOfField: string;
}
```

next I am creating form from list of questions. I created method and use it in

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.initForm();
  }

initForm() {
    const group: any = {};
    this.questions.forEach(question => {
      group[question.nameOfField] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

and I would like to write some tests but I am getting error:

```
should create FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
```

Where should I declare my array of questions and put it?

Comment: component.questions = []..?

Comment: If the "questions" property is a @input, you just have to initialize it on the unit test before you call your first detectChanges